# How to add default option in dropdown in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm creating a form date field which display day,month in drop down format. My problem is how can i add an option in it who's value is 0, so that when user dont want to select date 0 is stored in DB.

```
->add('monthPaymentDate', 'date', array(
        'widget' => 'choice',
        'empty_value' => array('year' => false, 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),
        'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        'input' => 'string',
        'required' => true,
    ))
```

Comment: `0` is not a valid `date` value, so you basically cannot do that.

Comment: but i want to store something when user select empty option otherwise it gives error.

Comment: So make it not `'required' => true,` and `nullable` in database?

Comment: 'empty_value' => array('year' => false, 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),

this line give me option like below

<option selected="selected" value="">Day</option>

as you can see its value is empty. i want its value to be set to 0 or something from which i can check user left it blank

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your entity:

```
public function setMonthPaymentDate($monthPaymentDate){
    if (!$monthPaymentDate instanceof Datetime){
       $date = 0; 
    }
    $this->monthPaymentDate = $monthPaymentDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding placeholder to the field.

```
->add('monthPaymentDate', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'choice',
    'empty_value' => array('year' => false, 'month' => 'Month', 'day' => 'Day'),
    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    'input' => 'string',
    'required' => true,
    'placeholder'=>'Choose a date'

))
```

Then the default value will be always null.